# parse Data Definition Template in oracle apps

Tags: java, xml, oracle, datatemplate

Is there any standard oracle parser to parse Data Template(.xml) file using PLSQL or Java.
For example, I want to parse the following data template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252" ?>    
<dataTemplate name="Employee Listing" description="List of Employees" v
 ersion="1.0">
<parameters>- Defines a single parameter for the Department Number 
            - with default of 20:
       <parameter name="p_DEPTNO" dataType="character" 
    defaultValue="20"/>
    </parameters>
<dataQuery>
   <sqlStatement name="Q1">
      <![CDATA[SELECT DEPTNO,DNAME,LOC from dept 
              order by deptno]]>
   </sqlStatement>
 <xml name="empxml" expressionPath=".//ROW[DEPTNO=$DEPTNO]"> - Defines name
  -  and link to DEPTNO in Q1
 <url method="GET" realm="" username="" password="">
file:///d:/dttest/employee.xml</url> - Defines url for xml data
</xml>  
</dataQuery>-
 <dataStructure>- The following section specifies the XML hierarchy 
                - for the returning data: 
     <group name="G_DEPT" source="Q1" 
      <element name="DEPT_NUMBER" value="DEPTNO"  />
     <element name="DEPT_NAME"   value="DNAME"/>
- This creates a summary total at the department level based 
- on the salaries at the employee level for each department:                 
     <element name="DEPTSAL" value="G_EMP.SALARY" 
      function="SUM()"/>
               <element name="LOCATION" value="LOC"  />
       <group name="G_EMP" source="empxml">
          <element name="EMPLOYEE_NUMBER" value="EMPNO" />
          <element name="NAME" value="ENAME"/>
          <element name="JOB" value="JOB" />
          <element name="MANAGER" value="MGR"/>
          <element name= "HIREDATE" value="HIREDATE"/>
          <element name="SALARY" value="SAL"/>
        </group>      
   </group>        
  </dataStructure>
</dataTemplate>
```

In the above Data Template, I want to check whether the template is valid or not by checking all the opening and closing tags.
In addition to this, I want to retrieve the attribute values from the above template. For Example, element tag contains attribute "name" and "value". I want EMPLOYEE_NUMBER and EMPNO, NAME and ENAME, etc.

I checked dbms_xmldom and dbms_xmlparser however they are used to parse simple XML file output.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is more related to parsing the XML and less related to oracle. With [a data projection library](http://xmlbeam.org) (Disclosure: I'm affiliated with that project), your problem is quickly solved:

```
public class ParseTemplate {

    @XBDocURL("resource://data.xml")
    public interface Template {

        public interface Field {

            @XBRead("./@name")
            String getName();

            @XBRead("./@value")
            String getValue();
        }

        @XBRead("//group[@name='G_EMP']/element")
        List<Field> getFields();
    }

    @Test
    public void readAttributes() throws IOException {
        List<Field> fields = new XBProjector().io().fromURLAnnotation(Template.class).getFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            System.out.println(field.getName() + " " + field.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

This JUnit test prints out every field with names and values:

```
EMPLOYEE_NUMBER EMPNO
NAME ENAME
JOB JOB
MANAGER MGR
HIREDATE HIREDATE
SALARY SAL
```

Comment: You are retrieving field values based on name. However I want to retrieve field name and values both. My input will be any XML file. Not only Employee related info but also other info like department etc.

Comment: Ah, ok. I will refine my answer.

Comment: Done. Now field names and values are printed.

Comment: Is there any alternative to built-in XML Parser Present in eclipse? When we open any XML in Eclipse, it shows the XML in a Tree like Structure. I tried using JTree, however I am unable to get the query present in the CDATA. Even if I get the query, I want to edit the query in XML dynamically like we can do in Eclipse.

Comment: Under the tree like structure in the eclipse XML editor, click on the "source" tab.

Comment: I want to replicate that functionality. Do you have any source in Java?

Comment: Please create a complete and answerable question and provide more context (e.g example data, example code). I'm not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: i want to replicate the functionality of eclipse XML editor  using Java. For the above code, I want to display the output exactly the same when we load the XML file in eclipse like 2 tabs source and design. In design tab, I can see the tree structure of XML as well as I can edit the structure. In source tab, I can edit the source code and the plus-minus option must be present. If I click on plus then the XML tag should expand and if I click on minus then the XML tag should contract.

Comment: When saying "Please create a question", I meant by clicking [on the ask question button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). The comment section is not the place to ask or answer these kind of questions.